# How to use JQuery functions in Angular 5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I want to use titl.js in my `Angular 5` app. Here is what I did so far:

```
npm install jquery --save

npm install tilt.js --save
```

And then in my `.angular-cli.json`

```
"scripts": [
                "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
                "../node_modules/tilt.js/dest/tilt.jquery.min.js"
            ]
```

In the component which uses `tilt.js` I have:

```
declare var jQuery: any;
```

And

```
@ViewChild( 'LoginTitl' ) login_titl: ElementRef;
ngAfterViewInit() {
        jQuery( this.login_titl.nativeElement ).tilt( {
            scale: 1.1
        } );
    }
```

But I get the following error:

```
Property 'tilt' does not exist on type 'JQuery<any>'.
```

Comment: Take a look at this article https://hackernoon.com/how-to-use-javascript-libraries-in-angular-2-apps-ff274ba601af

Answer (score 0):

Just working now.
I don't know if this is the solution or not, but adding the following line made the code work.

```
import 'tilt.js';
```